# PHP tag doesnt close properly

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, tags

```
<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( wp_json_encode( $available_variations ) ); //WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
```

I have this php code in my WordPress theme, after `//WPCS: XSS ok. ?>` closing tag doesnt work properly. In same file with same comment line closing php tague works good. I run PHP version 7.0

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work properly? What happens when you try?

Comment: what do you mean are you getting any error when code runs?

Answer (score 8):

```
//WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
```

The `//` will make the rest of the line a comment. Remove the comment or use `/* */` instead.

Comment: I tried this, ?>"> stays grey, nothing changes. Even when i remove whole comment, everything stays same.

Comment: Use **/* WPCS: XSS ok. */ ?>">** or just remove **//WPCS: XSS ok.** completely.

Comment: @EnricoDias (and all upvoters) [Per the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php), the `//` would _not_ include the closing PHP tag as part of the comment.  "?> breaks out of PHP mode and returns to HTML mode, and // or # cannot influence that."

Comment: @PatrickQ I didn't know that, I just copied the code to my editor and it grayed out the rest of the line. Thanks for pointing out.